# What's wrong with Laravel foreign key?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to create a foreign key using Laravel's migration.

```
 Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsinged();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->longText('body');
        $table->timestamp('published_at');
        $table->timestamps();

    });


    Schema::table('articles', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

I'm getting the following error, when I do `php artisan migrate`

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL: alter ta     ble `laravel_articles` add constraint
>   articles_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`     ) references
>   `laravel_users` (`id`) on delete cascade) `

Comment: @MarkBaker does not work!!

Comment: Is this the same migration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the method name. It's supposed to be `unsigned()` not `unsinged()`:

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->longText('body');
    $table->timestamp('published_at');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The Schema Builder uses [`Fluent`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Fluent.php) to chain the methods, which doesn't throw an exception even if the chained method `unsinged` doesn't exist. The `articles` table would still be created despite the typo, but the `user_id` column would be a signed integer, and since the `id` column in the `users` table is an unsigned integer it will prevent the constraint from being created.